# Add additional beans from xml definition into application context that is already initialized in runtime

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, applicationcontext

As you can see in the code below,
I want to load two xmls, `A.xml` and `B.xml`, into `ApplicationContext` separately. I am currently using the parent/child context relationship. But when I do this, I get different instance of class `C`.

Is there any way to fetch the instance of class `C` that is initialized while loading `A.xml` and use the same instance in `B.xml`?

A.xml-->

```
<import resource="classpath*:c.xml" />
<bean id="testA" class="com.TestA">
    <property name="testC">
        <ref bean="cBean" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

B.xml-->

```
<import resource="classpath*:c.xml" />
<bean id="testB" class="com.TestB">
    <property name="testC">
        <ref bean="cBean" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

C.xml-->

```
<bean id="cBean" class="com.TestC">
</bean>
```

And here is the relevant code:

```
context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("A.xml");  

context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[]{B.xml}, context);

((AbstractApplicationContext) context).registerShutdownHook();
```

output-->

```
  In Test A-->com.TestC@1df177.
  In Test B-->com.TestC@1ad8c79
```

Answer (score 1):

A and B compose a hierarchical context. That is A is a normal context that here contains 2 beans A and B, while B is a child context that contains 2 beans, B and a copy of C and can access to beans from its parent context.

Hierarchical contextes is a widely used feature, but you shall not duplicate beans from the parent context in child. If you do, beans from parent and child will use a different copy for any duplicated bean -> what you get here.

How to fix:

Simplest way is to not import C in B. That way bean C only lies in A but is still accessible from B thanks to the parent-child relation.

B.xml-->

```
<bean id="testB" class="com.TestB">
    <property name="testC">
        <ref bean="cBean" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: is there any other solution for it? beacuse i have to import c.xml in other two Xmls.

Comment: @nitinnimje could you explain why you need to import C into B when it is already imported into A and from this can be referenced from B?

Comment: Consider scenario where i require one object that is initialized in context before application starts and require same instance after application starts.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have no need to use 3 different xml files. You can do this as following;

```
<bean id="cBean" class="com.TestC">
</bean>
<bean id="testA" class="com.TestA">
    <property name="testC">
        <ref bean="cBean" />
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="testB" class="com.TestB">
    <property name="testC">
        <ref bean="cBean" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

This means TestC, TestA, TestB all are singleton bean where TestC bean is Injected by Property/Setter to TestA and TestB.

Now if you want TestC have same instance to TestA and TestB then do as following;

```
public class TestA{
   //Global Declaration
   private TestC testC;
   // Setter Injection
   public void setTestC(TestC testC){
      this.testC = testC
   }
   //some methods which will be called from main
}

public class TestB{
   //Global Declaration
   private TestC testC;
   // Setter Injection
   public void setTestC(TestC testC){
      this.testC = testC
   }
   //some methods which will be called from main
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply,But i have to use two separate A.xml & B.xml.Its the application requirement.

Comment: Its ok if you have to manage different xml config files but it all same. And as   u inject all your beans as singleton; IOC will manage single instance for those beans. If you need to share through bean to bean you just declare it globally.

Comment: Can u give some example of it??